# find duplicate values in between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables: `Customer1` and `Customer2`. Both tables' fields are the same, but employee names are different. Some of the employee are repeated in both tables.

I want to find the employees that are duplicated across both tables.

Sample data:

```
Customer 1

    ID  Name     Designation  salary
    1   User1     Developer    5000
    1   User2     Developer    5000
    1   User5     Developer    5000
    1   User1     Developer    5000


Customer 2

    ID  Name     Designation  salary
    1   User1     Developer    5000
    1   User2     Developer    5000
    1   User3     Developer    5000
    1   User1     Developer    5000

Result

    ID  Name     Designation  salary
    1   User1     Developer    5000
    1   User2     Developer    5000
```

`User1` and `User2` are in both tables many times, but I want to count them only once. I really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Usually when you have numbered tables like this, you have a bad design.  Which I think you have here.  What happens when you have 3, 4, 5 or more customers?  a table for each?

Answer (score 1):

You can join the two tables and the print out the distinct records from Customer1 that are left:

```
SELECT distinct customer1.*
FROM customer1 
    INNER JOIN customer2 ON
        customer1.id = customer2.id 
        AND customer1.name = customer2.name
```

Comment: wokring but its comes many count i want single count its  mean user1 comes two types after execute query i want single time

Comment: Does user1 come with two different salaries or two different "designations" or some other field that makes the two records distinct from eachother?

Comment: user 1 same  not different its comes   with both tables two or three times  but i want only one count when trying to find repeated values

Comment: Right... but you have multiple records for the same user in your customer1 table. They are not distinct. They have a different salary or a different designation and so you must choose one or the other. You MUST supply that logic even if it's "Choose a random on I don't care". Neither me nor your database can make that decision for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL` & do aggergation :

```
select id, name, Designation, salary
from (select c1.id, c1.name, c1.Designation, c1.salary
      from Customer1 c1
      union all
      select c2.id, c2.name, c2.Designation, c2.salary
      from Customer2 c2
     ) c
group by id, name, Designation, salary
having count(*) > 1;
```